# How do I make it so that when my laptop is not connected to the docking station, that only a single monitor is recognized?

Tags: multiple-monitors, docking-station

I have two external monitors connected to my laptop docking stations (total of 3 monitors including my laptop screen).  When I disconnect my laptop from the docking station, it still operates as though multiple monitors exist so programs open but I can’t access them because they are on screens that don’t actually exist.  How do I rectify this so that when my laptop is not connected to the docking station, that only a single screen is recognized?

Comment: You'll need to supply the make & model of your laptop, as well as the operating system.

Comment: Is there an "eject" or "undock" button? Do you use it? IIRC, in WinXP, a new button was added to the start menu.